# How to OrderBy reference table column in Entity framework

Tags: sql, database, linq, entity-framework

I have 2 tables with reference like : `Order` & `Product` 

I am using EF. Now I have a page where it shows like this :

OrderNo  |  OrderDate  |  ProductName  |  Price

There is a foreign key of Product table (ProductID) and I am showing `o.Product.ProductName` 

Now I want to `OrderBy` the list by Product Name which is in Product Table. 

How can I do this?

FYI : `ProductID` in `Order` Table is `Nullable`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it seems you have a navigation property `Product` in `Order` class

so you could do

```
.OrderBy(o => (o.Product == null) ? string.Empty : o.Product.ProductName)
```

you could also do in two pass

```
.OrderByDescending(o => o.Product == null) //or OrderBy, depending if you want null first or last
.ThenBy(o => (o.Product == null) ? string.Empty : o.Product.ProductName);
```

Answer (score 1):

In more complex case the code could look like this

```
.OrderByDescending(x => 
    !x.CONTACTPERSON.Any() 
        ? 0 
        : x.CONTACTPERSON.Max(
            y => !y.INTERACTIONENTRY.Any()
            ? 0
            : y.INTERACTIONENTRY.Max(z => z.InteractionEntryID)) 
    )
```